# a kind of dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu

I have made a dropdownlist, where first fild is empty:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID_firma, Model.firmaList, string.Empty)
```

How make a dropdownlist where in first "empty" field I will can write a name from dropdownlist?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're asking.  Are you talking about an edit-able dropdownlist??

Answer (score 0):

As Shark said, you need to clarify what you're asking for. But it sounds like you want some sort of Combo Box -- a drop down list that can accept typed values. Check out http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx. You would probably want to use it with the DropDownStyle property set to DropDownList rather than the default DropDown; this will allow the user to type values directly, but only those that are already in the list. I've found the Official Ajax Control Toolkit stuff to be pretty high quality and easy to integrate in most projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Telerik's Combobox which is an open source project with many features and users. see [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox) demo

Comment: The Telerik MVC controls are absolutely amazing.